# Angular 15 - SCSS background image fetch from assets folder returns 404

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, background-image

I am facing a weird issue when trying to load an image file from assets directory to SCSS file. Even it is not working in the inline style.

```
.register-form-container {
    background-image: url("/assets/images/layout-1/cover.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

It shows 404 response for the image in the browser network tab -

[image]
[image]

There is an error when I remove the starting slash from the URL -

```
.register-form-container {
    background-image: url("assets/images/layout-1/cover.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

If gives an error when compiles the code -

> Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

assets directory is added to the `angular.json` file -

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets"
]
```

Here is my `package.json` file -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "ng-observe": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
```

I can not figure out what is the possible issue behind that.

**Update:**

After building the code here it saves the assets files -

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you just make the path `/images/layout-1/cover.png`?

Comment: It does not work as well @ChrisGilardi

Comment: I recommend building your application, and then view the output to see where your image ends up. You should be able to use that path to reference the image.

Comment: After building the application it saves the files in assets directory. I added a screenshot to my question. @ChrisGilardi